# Parsing double nested JSON - Volley

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-volley

I'm trying to parse a JSON from a url but the JSON happens to be double nested, and I'm not sure how to make it work with my code
Here's the JSON and its [link](https://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=London&state=England&country=United%20Kingdom&key=f7a80239-3737-4a26-8ce6-71c2bc4ca1f5):

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "data":{
      "city":"London",
      "state":"England",
      "country":"United Kingdom",
      "location":{
         "type":"Point",
         "coordinates":[
            0.040725,
            51.456357
         ]
      },
      "current":{
         "weather":{
            "ts":"2022-03-12T19:00:00.000Z",
            "tp":9,
            "pr":1008,
            "hu":76,
            "ws":5.14,
            "wd":130,
            "ic":"01n"
         },
         "pollution":{
            "ts":"2022-03-12T19:00:00.000Z",
            "aqius":27,
            "mainus":"p2",
            "aqicn":9,
            "maincn":"p2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Code:**

```java
 JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    response -> {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                            //Accessing "data" in the JSON
                            jsonArray.put(response.get("data"));


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String cityName = data.getString("city");
                                String stateName = data.getString("state");
                                String countryName = data.getString("country");

                             
                              
                            }
                            //Notifying the adapter of the new changes
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
            requestQ.add(request);
    }
```

**GOAL:**

I want the function to read "current" and then "weather" and then get the value of "tp" just like how I'm getting the value of cityName, stateName etc
I'm aware that this question has been answered before but I didn't find something for double nested JSONs

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the nested object by

> yourObject.getJSONObject("weather")

In your case, it would be:

```
data.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("weather").getInt("tp");
```

Also, you could use the library *gson* to map the json string to Java class.